24.04 crashes with kernel 6.8
After starting and logging in, the computer crashes with "linux kernel 6.8.0-35-generic", but works without crashes with "linux kernel 6.5.0-35-generic"... Even using the LIVE CD, too The computer crashes, I downloaded it more than once on different connections and days, the result was always the same. A few days ago I was using 22.04 and a week ago I updated to 23.10, and yesterday I updated to 24.04. I need help to solve it, because even if the computer does not crash with Kernel 6.5, it is not working completely well, and I want to use 24.04 with Kernel 6.8. Thank you and I await your response.
24.04
6.5
6.8

I suggest booting to 6.5 and then installing 6.8.0-31, because that kernel works ok for me, but 6.8.0-35 really doesn't work for me at all.

Hello... Unfortunately for me the version 6.8.0-31 didn't work, the video drive and the wirelle drive are missing... I tried others each with different problems... the one that works with some errors is still 6.5.0-35... My machine is an HP laptop with a first generation I5 processor with 8Gb Ram and SSD 256... I believe that my hardware is not the problem... Even so, I still need help...

Hello guys, Thanks you... I reinstalled SO, backing to 22.04. See you later!
